# Android не работает Notification

Tags: android

Приложение собирается, ошибок не выдает, но уведомление не появляется. Запускаю на 9 андроиде.

**Код:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 101;
private static String CHANEL_ID = "test chanel";
private EditText editText;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String textForNotification = editText.getText().toString();

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANEL_ID)
                            .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                            .setContentText(textForNotification)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                    NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, builder.build());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, у вас дело в том, что не создан канал для уведомлений. Попробуйте вот этот код на [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) использовать для создания канала (используйте вызов этого метода вместо имени канала) для ОС>=8

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun createNotificationChannel(
    context: Context,
    channelId: String,
    channelName: String
): String {
    val chan = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    chan.lightColor = Color.BLUE
    chan.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
    val service = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    service.createNotificationChannel(chan)
    return channelId
}
```