# Почему не появляется уведовление?

Tags: android

Пытаюсь вызвать уведомление из сервиса, но почему-то его нет.
//Notification

`

```
//Notification
                            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp)
                                            .setContentTitle("Status")
                                            .setContentText("Voltage: "+currentVoltageStr)
                                            .setPriority(-2);
                            int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;
                            Intent targetIntent = new Intent(context, HomeFragment.class);
                            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                            NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                            assert nManager != null;
                            nManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

`

Comment: Скорее всего вам надо указывать канал для уведомлений или запускать на старых версиях ОС, например на 5 или 6 версии.

Comment: Попробуйте вот [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1099752/17609) канал создавать. Добавлять его надо в `NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel)`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Создал канал и все заработало, спасибо)